# animation only works the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly simple jquery animation on an absolute positioned div but it's only working the 1st time the function is called. Any subsequent times nothing happens.

```
var originalPixels = '80px',
    right:80px,
    newPixels = '50px',                                                                |     
    className = 'dangerous-attack-home';

$('.inner-animation-container').addClass(className);

$('.' + className).animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 1000, function(){
    $('.' + className).animate({
        right: newPixels
    }, 1000, function(){
        $('.' + className).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function(){
            $('.' + className).attr('right', originalPixels);
            $('.inner-animation-container').removeClass(className);
        });
    });
});
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated

C

Comment: "1st time the function is called"... are you referring to the first object with '.inner-aimation-container' class? Do you have a fiddle with this example?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'subsequent'? Do you mean when every time the page is refreshed? Or is there a certain trigger that starts the animation?

Comment: try to separate animate functions with colon, like `$(element).animate({ staf here}, time).animate({ another staf here}, time)`

Comment: If you haven't already, try printing out the CSS values for '.dangerous-attack-home'. It doesn't look like they're being reset so the animation can be played again. This will also give you some insight into what may be wrong if it is a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works fine.

Just watch class names and variables carefully.

```
var originalPixels = '80px',
right = '80px',
newPixels = '50px',                                                                   
className = 'dangerous-attack-home';

$('.inner-animation-container').addClass(className);

$('.' + className).animate({
    opacity: 1
}, 1000, function(){
    $('.' + className).animate({
        right: newPixels
    }, 1000, function(){
        $('.' + className).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 1000, function(){
            $('.' + className).attr('right', originalPixels);
            $('.inner-animation-container').removeClass(className);
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cbeP2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. The problem was actually the event not firing rather than a problem with the animation.